# How to reorganize Icon view

Tags: macos, folders, icon

After I delete and/or add files to a folder, the icon view is screwed up (see screenshot). How do I  reorganize it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Finder, you can just Control - click (hold down Control on the keyboard, then click the mouse / trackpad), and from the menu that pops up, select Cleanup By -> Name, or however you'd like to sort the items.

Comment: I see "Arrange By", not "Cleanup By", but it does the job. Thanks.